# In which Star Trek: The Next Generation episodes did Patrick Stewart not appear?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actors

I'm a little confused by what I see on Wikipedia.

The [wikipedia article for Patrick Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart) says he appeared in **176** episodes of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.  The [wikipedia article for the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) says there were **178** episodes.  Which two episodes did Stewart/Picard not appear in?

I know Wikipedia may not always be the best place for information but I'm trusting it in this case :)

Comment: Are we counting the final episode of Enterprise?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Patrick Stewart appeared in every episode; there's a discrepancy in how those two pages are counting.

*Star Trek: The Next Generation* aired [176 episodes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1). However two of those episodes, the premiere episode "Encounter at Farpoint" and the series finale "All Good Things...", were feature-length episodes. As originally broadcast, and as they're present on official home media releases, they were each about two hours long; that makes them hard to [syndicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_syndication) (typical network scheduling in North America doesn't like shows longer than an hour), so re-runs of each are typically split into two parts.

This is also apparent from Wikipedia's [list of the show's episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_episodes); the tables number each episode, but the series premiere and series finale each get two numbers (click to embiggen):

[image]

[image]

Comment: As an aside, I recall in my youth seeing the [*M\*A\*S\*H* series finale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodbye,_Farewell_and_Amen) in five parts. That's just criminal

Comment: They're only two hours after adding in commercials. ;) I believe they're about 1 hr 20 min without them (40 min per episode).

Comment: @jpmc26 respectively 1:27 and 1:32 according to my DVD (or 43-45 minutes for a regular episode). But they occupy a two-hour network timeslot, so I'm content to admit the simplification

Answer (score 39):

Per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)):

> Patrick Stewart (**Captain Jean-Luc Picard**) and Jonathan Frakes
>   (**Commander William T. Riker**) are the only actors to appear in **every
>   episode** of the series.

That being said, Picard only had a single (pre-taped) appearance in [TNG: Thine Own Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thine_Own_Self) as the actor Patrick Stewart was doing a one Man "A Christmas Carol" show in London at the time of filming. His appearance was mandated by his contract and it's likely that they simply recycled cut footage from another episode to insert his single line.

> **PICARD:** *What's the last thing you remember?*

Comment: There had to have been at least one episode with no Picard, only Locutus.

Comment: @Spencer - Alas, no. He was Picard at the start of the first episode and Picard at the end of the second episode.

Comment: So, check-mate Borg! Our Captain is protected by his contract! The best anti-assimilation weapon ever :)